# SQLite Does index help when querying using the same column

Tags: database, sqlite, database-indexes

```
CREATE INDEX idx_ex1 ON ex1(a,b,c);

select a,b 
from ex1 as res 
join ex2,ex3 
where a=<somevalue> 
and b = <somevalue> 
and c =ex2.t  
and c= ex2.r
```

Does indexing c help us in this scenario ? Do we need to write the SQL query in different way to get benefits of indexing in this scenario.?

Comment: I don't know about SQLList but in every other database: No Indexes are used automatically without any code change. PS your SQL doesn't appear to make any sense, i.e. you `join` but no `on` and you have commas between table in your `join` statement

Comment: Show the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) with and without the index.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Comma is the still-current pre-1992 inner join syntax. It is a cross join with lower precedence than "explicit" JOINs. Although the standard (ha ha) says (INNER) JOIN needs ON, that's not always enforced, whence it is taken as CROSS JOIN. Anyway the simplest collective description of all these inner joins is that they're all just cross joins filtered by ON and WHERE. The language only actually needs ON for outer joins.

Comment: The language doesn't even need ON for outer joins. However at the very least I suggest not mixing the two different syntaxes. As usual the OP is nowhere to be seen....